# How to loop through an array to concatenate data

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I need to loop through my array of data and concatenate `DogBreedName` with `DogName` and place that in a new array. An example of the end result I am looking for is German Shepard - Bailey, German Shepard - Jimbo, Black Lab - Vader.

I have tried using a for loop to achieve my result but I am getting errors of `undefined` or a returned result of `NaN`. I believe I am on the right track but my syntax is wrong. Below is my array `dogData` and my for loop of what I have tried.

```
var dogData = [{
    "DogBreedId": 2,
    "DogBreedName": "German Shepard",
    "DogBreedCount": "German Shepard (2)",
    "Dog": [{
        "DogId": 4,
        "DogBreedId": 2,
        "DogName": "Bailey",
        "Abbreviation": "BY",

      },
      {
        "DogId": 8,
        "DogBreedId": 2,
        "DogName": "Jimbo",
        "Abbreviation": "JO",
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "DogBreedId": 1,
    "DogBreedName": "Black Lab",
    "DogBreedCount": " (1)",
    "Dog": [{
      "DogId": 1,
      "DogBreedId": 1,
      "DogName": "Vader",
      "Abbreviation": "VD",
    }, ]
  },
]

function dogList() {
  var dogs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < dogData.length; i++) {
    dogs += dogData[DogBreedName] + "-" + dogData[Dog[DogName]];
    console.log(dogs);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate properly by using its index.

```
obj = dogData[i];
```

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var dogData = [{
      "DogBreedId": 2,
      "DogBreedName": "German Shepard",
      "DogBreedCount": "German Shepard (2)",
      "Dog": [{
          "DogId": 4,
          "DogBreedId": 2,
          "DogName": "Bailey",
          "Abbreviation": "BY",

        },
        {
          "DogId": 8,
          "DogBreedId": 2,
          "DogName": "Jimbo",
          "Abbreviation": "JO",
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "DogBreedId": 1,
      "DogBreedName": "Black Lab",
      "DogBreedCount": " (1)",
      "Dog": [{
        "DogId": 1,
        "DogBreedId": 1,
        "DogName": "Vader",
        "Abbreviation": "VD",
      }, ]
    },
  ];

  function dogList() {
    var dogs = [],
      lenDogData = dogData.length, obj, lenDog, objDog, name = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < lenDogData; i++) {
      obj = dogData[i];
      

      if (obj.Dog && obj.Dog.length > 0) { // Check if obj.Dog exists and have items.
        lenDog = obj.Dog.length;

        for (var j = 0; j < lenDog; j++) { // Iterate over obj.Dog array.
          objDog = obj.Dog[j];
          name = obj.DogBreedName;
          name += " - ";
          name += objDog.DogName; // Concat the name (DogBreedName - DogName)
          dogs.push(name);
        }

      }

    }
    return dogs;
  }

  var result = dogList();
  console.log(result);

}());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  position: relative !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Also if use `[]` notation for property names they need to be quoted strings like `objDog['DogName']`

Comment: How would I get the result to display as German Shepard - Bailey, German Shepard - Jimbo, Black Lab - Vader. I think the name object needs to be cleared but if I do something like name = " " it gets rid of DogBreedName and just returns  - Bailey  ,  - Jimbo , - Vader

Comment: I edited the answer to display the correct result. Thanks Danny for pointing me in the right direction